# Running Python 2.6 on a system with Python 2.4 (no admin rights)

Tags: python, debian

I have following issue: The Debian server I am working on has python 2.4 but I need to run `openpyxl` which only works on 2.6+.

I don't have administrative rights to install a newer version of python. Can I run `openpyxl` on 2.4, or maybe can I run python 2.6 without installation?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Can you install python-2.6 in your home folder?

Comment: No, I can't install even there. Maybe could I copy python files and open interpreter manually by path?

Comment: This seems to be more a question of "how can I install 'X' given constraint 'Y'?" and as such should be migrated to serverfault or maybe superuser

Comment: so maybe, is there a way to use openpyxl in python 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/) to run your code, as it has a 2.7.2.1 version, but I'm not sure about it.  I've used this before but never with packages.